# IAM policy to specific S3 bucket not effective without ListAllMyBuckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've specified the IAM access policy for one specific S3 bucket that's working fine with ListAllMyBuckets action. However I don't want to list all buckets to the user. If I remove LisAllBuckets action then I get the error,

```
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 37A0TA0JGKQA56FJ; S3 Extended Request ID: yWLJEG4RSqGKXjphkcvfOUTCqPe6Qtq/aZUKek1LJ
```

error when trying to access using access key id & Secret access key thru my application. It looks this policy should work as per AWS guidelines https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/ - but its not working as expected. Can you pls help me to resolve this issue? Thanks.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ohdart-dev-assessments"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ohdart-dev-assessments/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: `ListAllMyBuckets` is used for obtaining a list of bucket names, but not bucket contents. It is an "all or nothing" command that lets users list the names of _all_ buckets, or _no_ buckets. It does not work on a bucket-by-bucket basis. What are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: Thanks John, I've created three S3 buckets for each environment(Dev/QA and Prod) and respective programmatic IAM user and attached IAM policy only grant the access to specific bucket. From my application, if I call list buckets its showing all S3 buckets that exists with AWS account. I understand the only solution is moving to multi accounts AWS organizations architecture.

Comment: Why do those processes need the ability to obtain a list of buckets? If they know which buckets they should be using, then in theory they do not need the `ListAllMyBuckets` permission. It simply lets them view a _list_ of buckets. It does not grant any permission regarding the _contents_ of those buckets. Is it even a problem that they can see the names of all the buckets? What actual command are you running that gave rise to your original problem?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: This isn't supported by AWS.

---

I'm trying to set up the same scenario, both for least-priveleged access as well as for providing the simplest ease of use.

According [to the AWS knowedlege centre](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-access-certain-bucket/) (*as of 2022-07-22*) if you do not want to allow the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` action the recommended alternative is to allow the `s3:ListBucket` action (possibly providing a `Condition` so as to limit the paths accessible):

```json
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListBucket"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
      "s3:prefix": [
        "folder1/folder2/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and then to:

> Provide the user with a direct console link to the S3 bucket or folder. The direct console link to an S3 bucket looks like this:

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/folder1/folder2/
```